# Printing Issues with Lato Font

Tags: pdf, fonts, printing, truetype, opentype

There is another thread regarding a similar topic already, but I am still a little bit confused. "superuser.com/questions/901940/problems-printing-lato-font" (Cant post more than 2 links...)

However, I cannot comment on that since I am new and thus making a new thread.

@TD.512 (if you ever read this). I followed your suggestions of going to "latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts" then hit TTF.

After I downloaded the font,it still says OpenType Layout, Truetype Outline, just as @bama mentioned in his/her reply.

It does mention on the website saying that this is a "Lato fonts in TrueType-​​flavored Open­Type for­mat (.ttf)" (latofonts.com).

So my question is, does this consider as a real TrueType Font?

Here is a picture of what it looks like on the print. [All Lato fonts are messed up, while other fonts I tested with are fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3FmU.jpg) I had tried exporting to PDF and then printed it. Yet no luck.

That is printed from a Post Script Driver on a Xerox Phaser 7800GX. PCL6 driver prints out fine.

The reason why I ask is because some of the clients might print out wrongly too if they don't use the correct drivers, and it would look bad on my company for sending them defective PDFs. Ha...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: whoops, didn't see this till now

Comment: @TD.512 Hey! No worries! I stopped using that font. haha.Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on the Phaser 7800. however, the font prints fine as long as the point size is 25 points or larger. Anything smaller looks like the image you posted.